# Finding the highest value in an array, but what if the highest value exists two or more places in the array?

Tags: java

In my program I have a an array which I have to find out what place in the array has the highest value. The only problem is that what if the highest value exists in two or more places in the array?

These are ways to find the highest value, but they do not work if the highest value is the same in two more places?

```
for (int counter = 1; counter < decMax.length; counter++)
{
     if (decMax[counter] > max)
     {
      max = decMax[counter];
     }
}

System.out.println("The highest maximum for the December is: " + max);




public int maxValue(int array[]){
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    list.add(array[i]);
  }
 return Collections.max(list);
}




public int maxValue(int array[]){
  int max = Arrays.stream(array).max().getAsInt();
  return max;
}
```

Comment: The two `maxValue` methods you got in your code give you the highest value, not it's place. Having that value you can iterate over your dataset and if the value is equal to the highest print that place or something.

Comment: Genious! Thanks!

Comment: What about `Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(max_value)`? It returns the index of the first element with this maximum value.

Comment: @RobertKock I'd assume OP wants to find all indices of `max_value`, not just the first.

Comment: Correct @RobertKock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a `List<Integer>` having the locations/indexes where the max value was found.

As you found the `max` use it to find the indexes where it was present in the array:

```
public List<Integer> maxValue(int array[]){
        int max = Arrays.stream(array).max().orElse(-1);
        return IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                        .filter(idx -> array[idx] == max)
                        .mapToObj(i -> i)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I did not get it to work? It says "cannot find symbols" to  "Collectors" and "IntStream" .

Comment: @Magnus2142 Add these 2 imports:
`import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;`

Answer (score 0):

A traditional loop may help if you do not want to iterate over your dataset twice:

```
List<Integer> findMaxValueIndexes(int[] array) {
    if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    // Use this list to remember which indexes hold the max value
    List<Integer> maxValueIndexes = new LinkedList<>();
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         if (array[i] > max) {
            maxValueIndexes = new LinkedList<>();
            maxValueIndexes.add(i);
            max = array[i];
         } else if (array[i] == max) {
            maxValueIndexes.add(i);
         }
    }

    return maxValueIndexes;
}
```

Comment: I'd have preferred using `maxValueIndexes.clear()` instead of `maxValueIndexes = new LinkedList<>();` inside a loop.